# How to set config load_system_dawg when using pytesseract to improve result?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to improve the result by changing params using pytesseract config. I am wondering if there is a possibility to change load_system_dawg and load_freq_dawg as specified in https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality#page-segmentation-method since the words I am trying to get are not really english, but co-ords like XYZ ### and some other unique sequences of letters. See screenshot

[image: minecraft screenshot]

I can adjust the config of --psm but get error of no such command line argument or a file not existing if I try --load_system_dawg 0. I dunno, seemed like it was worth a shot...

```py
params = r'--psm 11'
string = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config = params)
```

I'm assuming there isn't a way to do this through python but if I could be directed as to how to change it I would appreciate it as I don't know much in the way of C++. Will this change be initialized through pytesseract? Additionally I have also tried changing user-patterns but not sure if this is the better way to go

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the followings:

- [thresholding using cv2.inRange](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d97/tutorial_threshold_inRange.html)
- [Arithmetic Operations on Images](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/d86/tutorial_py_image_arithmetics.html).
- [Page segmentation methods](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html#page-segmentation-method)

For instance, if you apply threshold image will become:

[image]

Next apply `bitwise_not`:

[image]

Now if you read (Assuming image as a single uniform block of text.):

```
Hinecratt 1.14.4 1.14.4 / vanilla Javea: 136 51 64bit
68 fps (8 chunk updates) T: inf vsune fancy-clouds veo Hem: 4ah 8757 2648NE
Integrated server @ 11 ms ticks, 13 tx, 735 rx Allocated: 814% 1664M6
C: 1615376 (5) 0: 15, pC: G66, pu: 6, ab: Se
c afte oe CPU: 16% AND Fiyzen 7 L786 ECight-Core Processor
Client Chunk Cache: 1659, 75 Display: 1926%1880 CHVIOIA Corporation?
ServerChunkCache: S734 GeForce OTA 1666 606/PCle/55E2
ninecrattoverworld FC: a 4.6.4 HVIDIA 431.68
42: S6L641 / 11.66668 ¢ 361.939 Targeted Block
Block: S61 11 361 Hinecrattiron_ore
Chunk: 13 11 3 in 18 @ 22
Facing: west (Towards negative 43 095.4 7 15.79 Targeted Fluid
Client Light: 11 (8 sky, 11 block? ninecrattempty
Server Light: (8 sky, 11 black?
CHS: 67 MH: 67
5H 3:67 0: 67 M: 67 ML: 67
Biome: minecrattdesert
Local Difficulty: 165 7/7 6.66 (Day 243
Looking at block: 295 16 361
Looking at liquid: 295 16 361
Sounds: 37247 + a7G
Debug: Pie Cehittl: hidden FPS + TPS Caltl: hidden
For hele: press Fa + oO
```

Code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread("sPQDo1c.png")

# Convert to the HSV color-space
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Threshold
thr = cv2.inRange(hsv, np.array([0, 0, 214]), np.array([179, 0, 225]))

# Bitwise-not
bnt = cv2.bitwise_not(thr)

# OCR
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(bnt, config="--psm 6"))

# Display
cv2.imshow("", bnt)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I'm using pytesseract version [0.3.7](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/)